# Serialzing form and posting ajax to function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass the form field values to a php function located into a file. The problem is that I can't understand how to pass that serialized form data to the function from this ajax to a function in php.

```
$('#insert_news').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#insert_news').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'includes/ajax.php',
        data: {
            action: 'insert_news',
            $('#insert_news').serialize(); // how do I add this data here?
        },
        success: function(datas) {
            $('#message').html(datas).show() /*fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000)*/ ;
        }
    });
});
```

This ajax passed the values to the file ajax.php right beyond. And from ajax.php is called the function located in functions.php.

ajax.php

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'insert_news') {
    $cp->insert_into_table('newss', array(
                                        'NewsTitle' => $_POST['title'], 
                                        'NewsDescrption' => $_POST['description'], 
                                        'Date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
                                        'status' => '1'
                                    )
                           );
}
```

function.php

```
public function insert_into_table($table_name, array $data){
    foreach($data as $col=>$value) {
        $cols[] = $col;
        $values[] = '\''.$value.'\'';
    }
    $cols = implode(', ', $cols);
    $values = implode(', ', $values);
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO $table_name ($cols) VALUES ($values)");
    echo "INSERT INTO $table_name ($cols) VALUES ($values)";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `serialize()` produces a URL encoded key value paired string, so you can't mix that with your data object.

You can use [`serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to get an array of objects, representing the form elements, then iterate over them and add them to a data object:

```
var data = { action: 'insert_news' };

$.each($('#insert_news').serializeArray(), function(){
    data[this.name] = this.value;
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'includes/ajax.php',
    data: data,
    success: function(datas) {
        $('#message').html(datas).show() /*fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000)*/ ;
    }
});
```

---

Side note: your PHP code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Consider using a Prepared Statement instead of concatenating user input into the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass serialized data via ajax to a function the way you are doing but your code needs slight modification.

```
$('#insert_news').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#insert_news').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'includes/ajax.php',
        data: {
            action: 'insert_news',
```

> ```
>             serializedData: form // use variable to assign data here
> ```

```
        },
        success: function(datas) {
            $('#message').html(datas).show() /*fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000)*/ ;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: tried adding the serializeddata with variable, but I get in php `Notice: Undefined index: title`, like somehow is not passing their names.

Comment: you have to debug by printing the post variable for the exact array format. You are getting that issue just because your array key will be different.

Comment: understood. Thank you, this is also a very easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#insert_news').submit(function(event) {
    var name = $("#t1").val();
    var pass = $("#t2").val();  //add more var as u need
    var key  = 0;

     var formName = new FormData();

     formName.append(key++,name)
     formName.append(key++,pass)    //append the the var to formdata


        $.ajax({
            url         :   'includes/ajax.php',
            dataType    :   'text',
            cache       :   false,
            contentType :   false,
            processData :   false,
            data        :   formName,                                    
            type        :   'post',

            success     :   function(data){
                        $('#message').html(data).show() /*fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000)*/ ;
                }

        });
});
```

this works fine for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use alternate like this

First : add hidden input for action on your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="insert_news"/>
```

Then your ajax post like this

```
$('#insert_news').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'includes/ajax.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(), // $(this) is from <form id="insert_news">
        success: function(datas) {
            $('#message').html(datas).show() /*fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000)*/ ;
        }
    });
});
```

And then use print_r on your ajax.php

```
print_r($_POST);
```